# A question which closely related to a lot of other questions that is not closed as dupe?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

For example: [How to select a graduate school](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56539/14341)

IMO, this question is fully answered by the linked questions in the comments. However, it doesn't well answered. However (again), I'm interested in the question itself.

I think it is exactly a dupe of the related questions, linked by ff524. However she doesn't do that. I wonder why.

Since I has interest with the question itself, should I upvote it, then vote to close as a dupe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a moderator vote is binding, I prefer not to cast a first or second close vote in many cases (specifically, in cases where I think it's more appropriate for the community to weigh in first.)

> I think it is exactly a dupe of the related questions, linked by ff524.

Then you should vote to close.

Comment: should I upvote it too?

Comment: @Ooker if you find it useful, sure. See [When should I vote up?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: just a note, I don't think the FAQ give me enough information, to the level of satisfy  me